# Avoid mspdbsrv when compiling in Visual Studio (2008)

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2008

When two visual studio processes compile in parallel, the second will reuse the instance of `mspdbsrv` started by the first one. So when the first build is terminated and the whole process tree terminated (e.g. by [Jenkins](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-9104)), the other build fails.

That bug report describes how to start it manually so it does not get killed. But the thing is also famous for occasionally forgetting to close files, which can fail the *next* build.

Is there a combination of options under which `mspdbsrv` would *not* be used at all?

---

Ok, I am looking for a *generic* answer, so I didn't include the current options at first. But the answer so far sounds like `mspdbsrv` shouldn't be used when some options are not used. Except in the trivial test project used (by CMake) to check whether MSC++ works they are not used, yet it does start `mspdbsrv.exe`. The trivial projects is a `.vcproj` file, compiled via `devenv.com CompilerIdC.vcproj /build Debug`. The build runs following commands for C:

> `cl.exe /Od /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /FD /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc90.pdb" /W0 /c /TC ".\CMakeCCompilerId.c"`
>
> `link.exe /OUT:".\CompilerIdC.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:"Debug\CompilerIdC.exe.intermediate.manifest" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /NODEFAULTLIB:"libc" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib ".\Debug\CMakeCCompilerId.obj"`
>
> `mt.exe /outputresource:".\CompilerIdC.exe;#1" /manifest ".\Debug\CompilerIdC.exe.intermediate.manifest"`

and following commands for C++:

> `cl.exe /Od /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /FD /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc90.pdb" /W0 /c /TP ".\CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp"`
>
> `link.exe /OUT:".\CompilerIdCXX.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:"Debug\CompilerIdCXX.exe.intermediate.manifest" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /NODEFAULTLIB:"libc" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib ".\Debug\CMakeCXXCompilerId.obj"`
>
> `mt.exe /outputresource:".\CompilerIdCXX.exe;#1" /manifest ".\Debug\CompilerIdCXX.exe.intermediate.manifest"`

This still starts the `mspdbsrv.exe`. I actually used the fact that it does to protect it from Jenkins killer for the time being.

The option `/FD` is injected by `devenv.com`. I've tried to run it via `msbuild`, but that invokes `vcbuild` (Visual Studio 2008) and that executes the same commands including the `/FD` option. And the WinCE targets are only supported by the Visual Studio generators in CMake, so I can't switch to make easily.

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but you can close it yourself with a command line call like `mspdbsrv.exe -stop`. You can also use the `-verbose` command line arg to gather a bit more information from it (coupled with the `-start` arg or any other arg in fact)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a common complaint, there's no existing feedback report for it on connect.microsoft.com.  Otherwise the recommended way to accelerate resolution of problems like this, you do get a Microsoft engineer to look at the issue.

And no, there is no specific option to *disable* mspdbsrv.exe.  There is only one for the opposite, to **enable** it.  The [/FS option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn502518.aspx) forces the compiler to use it.

Strong hints that you are using a compiler option that's not commonly used on build machines.  You did not document anything so guessing is required.  The number one candidate is the [/MP option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385193.aspx).  Which always requires the compiler to use mspdbsrv.exe since it will launch the compiler multiple times, each working on one of the source files that were passed.  A scenario where mspdbsrv.exe is required since each compiler instance is likely to want to write to the same .pdb file, particularly the program database specified in the [/Fd option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9wst99a9.aspx).

So look at your build scripts and remove /MP if you see it.  Document the options you pass to the compiler next.  Filing a feedback report at connect.microsoft.com is strongly recommended.

---

After update: your build server is using the /FD option incorrectly.  The MSDN Library article has this to say about it:

> /FD is only used by the development environment, and it should not be used from the command line or a build script.

I cannot predict what effect it has on mspdbsrv.exe, it very likely has one since /FS is strongly linked to /Gm which is strongly linked to /FD.  Removing the option is the obvious next step.

Comment: Visual Studio is definitely not uncommon compiler. But we still need some ancient version of it (Visual Studio 2008; the newer ones don't support WinCE and they are still used in custom devices) where I don't expect Microsoft to fix anything. And it's not like it was failing regularly. But occasionally it does and then it requires manual intervention, so I wanted to know whether there is a known case where it would not be used.

Comment: That was all clear, odd that you didn't improve your question.  Surely you know what compile options are used from the build log?

Comment: I know what options are used (it's easier to look in the compile options dialog). But that won't tell me whether there is a combination that will prevent use of mspdbsrv.

Comment: Sigh, major disconnect.  Why don't you leave it up to us to tell you this?  This site is not youtube.com, we can't see those options if you don't post them.  Do *not* post a screenshot of the option dialog, we need to know the exact command line that is being used.  One is enough.

Comment: Because the options that are there currently won't change the answer. I asked which questions affect whether mspdbsrv is used, _not_ how do I change my project. Because I prefer _generic_ answer. That said and looking at the options you mention, the test project for detecting compiler does not have either and does start `mspdbsrv`, so I now included the full command-lines from that project in the question.

Comment: There we go.  Using /FD on a command line build is always incorrect.  Mspdbsrv.exe is undocumented, you'll need to obtain the generic answer from Microsoft Support.  I seriously doubt you'll get one, you have a "no", maybe you get a "yes".

Comment: That's what the IDE does. It's built via `devenv.com CompilerIdCXX.vcproj /build Debug`.

Comment: Good Lord.  I have no idea left how to get you to document this properly.  I give up, call Microsoft Support.

Comment: I have a similar issue, where one build finishing in CI is causing another build to be indirectly killed off, so I'm looking to disable this thing as well. My command-line doesn't have /FD though: cl /Fd..\..\..\build\bin\x86\vc.pdb /I "..\..\..\..\util\build\include" /I "C:\DevEnv\Tools\Visual C++\VC\atlmfc\include" /DUNICODE /D_UNICODE /DWIN32 /GS /EHac /c /nologo /W3 /Zi /MT /Fo..\..\..\build\obj\x86\FileDialogEventHandler.obj FileDialogEventHandler.cpp

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you must already have tried setting "Generate Debug Info" -> No

Not sure if below came to your mind or not:
Try removing (or rename or move to other location) mspdbsrv.exe and related dlls (mspdb80.dll and mspdbcore.dll) and then see what happens.

This is just a wild guess but worth trying.